# TFS 2015 - Build controller offline after update 2

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I recently updated my TFS 2015 to TFS 2015 with Update 2. Everything went well but i wasn't able to queue builds anymore.

I logged in on the server and realized that I couldn't find my build controller anywhere (Still using XAML Build definitions).

The only thing i saw was this : [image: Where did it go?]

In my VS i saw this: [image: Offline]

Is the build controller / agent completly gone from TFS with update 2? Did i miss something in the release notes?

Any way to repair my situation?

Comment: XAML Build Controller/Agent info is now under **Additional Tools and Components > XAML Build Configuration** in the TFS Administration Console. Are your build services on the same server as your application tier? You possibly didn't re-configure your XAML build services after the upgrade.

Comment: Oh wow. Can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. Did the same thing myself :)